# jquery change event on dynamically added selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

This is my code, im planning on adding some selectors dynamically, but how do i make change functions into this??

here is my code

```
$("select#Accion").change(function(){
                var id = $("select#Accion     option:selected").attr('value');
                $("div#select").append("<table border=\"0\"     class=\"addin\"></table>");
                if(id.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')==1){
                    $("table.addin").append("<tr class=\"1\"><td><label class=\"Tipo\">Tipo:</label><td></tr><br /><tr class=\"2\"><td><select name=\"Tipo\" id=\"Tipo\"><option value=\"0\">Selecciona...</option><option value=\"1\">Primera Instalacion</option><option value=\"2\">Servicio Tecnico</option><option value=\"3\">Material</option><option value=\"4\">Demo/Trial</option></select></td></tr>");
                }else if(id.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')==2){

                }else if(id.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')==3){

                }
            });
            $("#container").on('change','select.Tipo', function(){
                console.log("TEst");
                $("table.addin > tr.1").append("<td><label class=\"Acuerdo\">Acuerdo:</label><td>");
            });
```

Comment: generating html like that makes kittens cry

Comment: how would you approach this then? different selectors need to be loaded because with every different option

Comment: Create your html layout first and then control the visibility of these elements based on the changed value.

Comment: Thanks, actually i was onto that, seems more simple. thanks for your time